# how to make video feed fullscreen in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

when i try to apply canny edge detection the borders of video is also getting detected and i want to know how to remove it. i am using inbuilt webcam to obtain the video and found that original frame has borders too. how to make the video full screen?

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXoPv.png)
[Canny Edge output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5VNd.png)

expected output

[Without Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2wtR.png)
[Without Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSir8.png)

```
import cv2

windowName = "Live"
cv2.namedWindow(windowName, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setWindowProperty(windowName,cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:  
    _,img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)
    cv2.imshow(windowName, edges)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try adding `cv2.namedWindow(windowName, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` and `cv2.setWindowProperty(windowName,cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)`

Comment: @iGian i still get the borders after adding those

Comment: Try this instead: cv2.namedWindow(windowName, `cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.moveWindow(windowName, 0, 0)
cv2.setWindowProperty(windowName, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)`

Comment: Try to set for Capture CAP_PROP_SAR_NUM  and CAP_PROP_SAR_DEN for 4:3 aspect ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your camera outputs images with borders, so you could look into the settings and try to disable it and thus solve the problem.

Another option is to create a smaller image, without the borders. You can do this with
`sub_image = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]`
For your images x1 is 0 and x2 is the image width. y1 is the first non-black pixel from the top, y2 the first non-black pixel from the bottom.

I've added code below that finds the Y1 and Y2 values and prints them to screen. It also shows the result. Once you have found proper Y values you'll only have the add the line that creates the sub_image to your code.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
# load image
img = cv2.imread("image.png",0)
# sum each row of the image
sumOfRows = np.sum(img, axis=1)

# Find the first and last row that has a sum value greater than zero, 
# which means its not all black. Store the found values in variables
for i in range(len(sumOfRows)):
    if sumOfRows[i] > 0:
        y1 = i
        print('First row: ' + str(i))
        break

for i in range(len(sumOfRows)-1,-1,-1):
    if sumOfRows[i] > 0:
        y2 = i
        print('Last row: ' + str(i))
        break

# create a new image based on the found values
roi = img[y1:y2,0:img.shape[1]]

#show image
cv2.imshow("Result", roi)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```